# Use devtools extensions with Chrome's remote devtools using --remote-debugging-port

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, electron, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am using Chromium's `--remote-debugging-port` flag in an electron app to remotely access the Devtools on a port. I want to use the React Devtools extension along with these Devtools. If I use Electron's API for installing the Devtools extension and open the Devtools inside Electron using `webContents.openDevtools()`, it works fine. 
But I am unable to get it working with the remote Devtools. Is there a way to enable the extensions for remote Devtools maybe using the Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Comment: The [protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) doesn't have anything like that, apparently.